# Anchor link jumping me to document root in Xenforo

Tags: html, anchor

I have an issue with what ought to be a very simple task: Create a BBCode tag to create a text anchor, and create another to jump to that text anchor.

However, something is going on, and it's causing my anchors to jump to the root of the website.

Here's the HTML generated by the BBCode:

```
<div id="section1">Section Header</div>
<a href="#section1">Goto Section Header</a>
```

However, when it's in the live page, clicking it will jump me to root of the website rather than the current page.  This is tested in Firefox and Chrome.  I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is a live sample page with the BBCode in use (text search section1 in the source for the anchors).  http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?help/bb-codes

As you can see, clicking on the link under "Goto" will take you to http://community.playstarbound.com/#section1 instead of http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?help/bb-codes#section1 as expected.

Is there anything external to this div and anchor tag that can cause this?

Comment: The page seems to contain two elements with `id="section1"`. Since IDs are supposed to be unique, it could be that this is confusing the browser.

Comment: It's an unfortunate bug, but it doesn't work here either: http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/expand-the-bb-code-selection.15492/#post-599631

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem**

The browser doesn't seem to recognize correctly the base URL of your page. So the relative URL of your anchor link is currently interpreted by the browser as

```
http://community.playstarbound.com/#some-anchor
```

when in fact it the actual URL should be

```
http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/expand-the-bb-code-selection.15492/#some-anchor
```

Since the link's URL differs from the current page's URL, it leads the browser to treat it as a regular link and not an internal anchor in the current page, thus redirecting you to the root of your site.

**Solutions**

1. Specify an absolute path in the anchor link.
2. **Edit:** As you suggested, correct the value specified in your site's `base` tag.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer.  Xenforo seems to add a `<base>` tag to the document, which is why I was having these issues.

Answer (score 2):

How I fixed it:

I could not correct the value specified in the `base` tag.  And I could not specify an absolute path.  Instead, I did a little javascript magic.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.hash = 'some-anchor';">
```

That fixed me right up.

Answer (score 1):

The in-page anchor many of us used in pre-MVC world certainly can cause a PITA in MVC. I've used two different kinds of fixes for it:

1. If you're simply using 'href=#' and don't need it to navigate anywhere, then use a jquery "e.preventDefault". As in:

```js
$('(Your attribute, class, and/or ID) a).click(function (e) {
  //whatever else you might want to do, i.e. highlight,etc...
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent in-page anchor from navigating to root of site
});
```

(I've seen enough **"href='#' "** in scripts, so I don't ask anymore and don't ask me why either).

2. If you're wanting to navigate somewhere else in the page, add a similar jQuery, but instead of e.preventDefault(), you'll just "return false;". For example, if you have an item `<span><a class="fa fa-arrow-down down-to-bottom" href="#footer">&nbsp;down</a></span>` that you need to go to page bottom, this will do that and shouldn't throw you out to the 'root':

```js
$('.down-to-bottom').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
});
```

Modify it however you want to go to somewhere besides the bottom (like to another "div") --just be sure to "return false;".

Either of these can probably be done in 'vanilla' javascript too. I usually use jQuery because it's easier for me and a lot of others.